# vba if <all of these> = value then

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

My code right now looks like this

```
For i = 1 To Rows.Count
    If (Cells(i, 24) = "Y" And Cells(i, 25) = "Y" And Cells(i, 40) = "Y") Then
            sum = sum + 1
    End If
End If
Next
```

I would like to make the If statement more compact by doing something like:

```
For i = 1 To Rows.Count
    If (Cells(i, 24) And Cells(i, 25) And Cells(i, 40)) = "Y") Then
            sum = sum + 1
    End If
End If
Next
```

But this doesn't work.

Is there a more compact form for writing this If statement, or am I stuck with the first version?

Comment: Last I checked you **can't** do that. Example: `if ((x or y or z) = true) then`, won't work. You must do: `if ((x = true) or (y = true) or (z = true)) then` (pseudo code). Also, 11 characters isn't much of a compact improvement.

Comment: @Insane: Testing `= true` is a *really bad* example, because, if `x`, `y`, and `z` are Boolean, then you *can* say `(x or y or z)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to compact the If statement:

```
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Sum = Sum + Abs(Cells(i, 24) & Cells(i, 25) & Cells(i, 40) = "YYY")

Next
```

Also, there is a performance issue with your code: `Rows.Count` = 1 million+ rows

You can loop through the Used Rows only: `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`

Comment: how is this related to the question?

Comment: It provides a compact version of the If statement

Comment: oh, I see it now. But the emphasis on the comment, not on the solution, could you please reformat you answer to make it answering the question first and commenting just after